# Many-To-Many relationship causes wrong result in Spring

Tags: spring, jpa, many-to-many

I have a project written in Spring and Kotlin. There are following entities with Many2Many relationship between them (Parent<->Child).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAR_PARENT")
class Branche(
    @Column(name = "ID")
    var id: UUID? = null,

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    var name: String,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    var status: Status = Status.ACTIVE,
) {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
    @JoinTable(
        name = "PAR_CHI",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "FK_PAR_ID")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "FK_CHI_ID")]
    )
    val children= mutableSetOf<Child>()
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHI_CHILD")
class Child(
    @Column(name = "ID")
    var id: UUID? = null,

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    var name: String,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    var status: Status = Status.ACTIVE,
) {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "children")
    val parents= mutableSetOf<Parent>()
}
```

Here is the repository:

```
@Repository
interface ParentRepository : JpaRepository<Parent, UUID> {
    @Query("select p from Parent p JOIN FETCH p.children cs where p.id=:id AND p.status=:status AND cs.status=:status")
    fun findByIdAndStatus(id: UUID, status: Status): Optional<Parent>
}
```

Here I have faced with two issues:

1. When the query above does not contain word `FETCH` (without eager loading of children), then accessing children field (causes lazy loading what actually is expected), new sql query is executed and all children have been loaded ignoring requested `status`, only id of parent is taken as query parameter. So, I decided to work around add make the loading eager in order to make single request and receive correct data (with requested status):

val result = parentRepository.findByIdAndStatus("some_uuid", Status.Active) // request 1
result.children // request 2 (when no fetch is set)

2. Even with this fix (by adding FETCH), query returns different result on H2. It works as expected on Postgresql, but on H2 Child elments with other all the statuses are returned. By the way, the SQL query looks correct on both DBs, just the result ist wrong. On both DBs single query is executed at the end.

Comment: You seem to be fighting against JPA which, when returning managed entities, is meant to give you a view of your Entity data as it is in the database. You are trying to filter your view of the children based on their status which is bad practice - the list will be incomplete, so JPA can't tell what to do when you modify the list and with it being designed to support caching, is why it is unsupported by the specification.

Comment: Options I see: If you want the children filtered by status, you'll have to query them directly with their parents (select c, p from .." and create a map with a list of children for each parent yourself. Don't then use the parent.children mapped relationship list from the entity and use your own. Alternatively you can add a filter to the mapping (provider specific) so that the entity always uses that filter - but you are stuck with it.